# Craft version 4.x: multiple instances of Craft in same hosting account

Tags: installation, multi-environment, hosting

This is related to me asking about [multiple instances of Craft in same hosting account root](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/37296/multiple-instances-of-craft-in-same-hosting-account-root) 2 years ago, but that was for version 3.x, since when `bootstrap.php` is now part of the Craft infrastructure.

I need to create a discrete dev environment in the same account as a production instance.

I can in principle create the following structure*:

```
.env <-- points to production DB
bootstrap.php
composer.json
composer.lock
craft
config/
modules/
storage/
templates/
vendor/
public_html/ <-- production web root
  index.php

dev/
  .env <-- points to dev DB
  bootstrap.php
  composer.json
  composer.lock
  craft
  config/
  modules/
  storage/
  templates/
  vendor/
dev.domain.com/ <-- dev web root
  index.php
```

Is it just a case of updating `require` for `bootstrap.php` in `dev.domain.com/index.php` ?

Or is there a need to `define` other paths and/or change the `craft` executable as well?

(*The above structure is *similar* to [option 2](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/37299/3507) laid out by Brandon 2 years ago, but not the same.)

---

I should add that the production instance is already in place so don't really want to alter it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just updated [my previous answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/37299/9) on the other Q&A post. (It’s not Craft 4-specific; the newer default project structure was introduced during Craft 3.x.)

Comment: Thanks Brandon. Will see how I get on.